# Stata identification of beta distribution alpha and beta

Tags: stata

When data is loaded into Stata variable names appear, and apparently I can make a  histogram to look at the distribution:

```
histogram *variablename*
```

But if a distribution appears to be a beta distribution, how is the alpha and beta found?

Comment: Research effort not in evidence. Do use basic search facilities such as `search` in Stata.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users discusses what is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`betafit` from SSC does this. Typing in Stata

```
 . search beta
```

would point to this (and indeed much else).

Example:

```
. clear

. set seed 2803

. set obs 100
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 100

. gen y = rbeta(2, 2)


. ssc install betafit
checking betafit consistency and verifying not already installed...
installing into !!! 
installation complete.

. betafit y

Iteration 0:   log likelihood =  12.898998  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood =  13.093709  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood =  13.094329  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood =  13.094329  

ML fit of beta (alpha, beta)                    Number of obs     =        100
                                                Wald chi2(0)      =          .
Log likelihood =  13.094329                     Prob > chi2       =          .

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
alpha        |
       _cons |   1.945302   .2606829     7.46   0.000     1.434373    2.456232
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
beta         |
       _cons |    2.11004   .2854789     7.39   0.000     1.550512    2.669568
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```